# Sparse matrix front reducing

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, sparse-matrix

There is a symmetric sparse matrix with large front. This matrix is created from graph. Element with position $(i,j)$ is not zero if nodes $i$ and $j$ are connected. 
What algorithms can be used for re-enumerating graph nodes to create matrix with lesser front?
I have only one option - [the Cuthill-McKee algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm). Is there anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "front", do you mean bandwidth? I've not been able to find any definition of the front of a matrix by searching.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The definition was near - on this site:
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11271/approximating-front-size-of-asymmetric-matrices
Anyway, reducing bandwith is just fine in my case, so I will be happy to see any suggestions for this. Thanks for your attention.